# django forms is not displayed via web

Tags: python, django, forms

Have some trouble with displayed form via web.
I'm using Django 1.6.2
In **forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    pk_post = forms.CharField(max_length=1, required=False)
    user_post = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=False)
    description_post = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)
```

In **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from report.models import Main, Data
from report.forms import ContactForm
from django.template import RequestContext, loader

def index(request):
    mainc = Data.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('report/index.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
       'mainc': mainc,
       })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))

def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        pk_post = form.cleaned_data['pk_post']
        user_post = form.cleaned_data['user_post']
        description_post = form.cleaned_data['description_post']
        p = Main.objects.get(pk=pk_post)
        p.data_set.all()
        p.data_set.create(user=user_post, description=description_post, data_date=timezone.now())
```

In **index.html** i'm added next code:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

But when I load index.html via browser I can see only "Submit" button. Table from **{{ form.as_table }}** not generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not sending the form in the context:

```
def index(request):
    mainc = Data.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('report/index.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
       'mainc': mainc,
       'form' : ContactForm() 
       })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Consider using [`render()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) instead of `HttpResponse`

Also, from the code you have shown, there is an issue with `def contact():` method too, I am assuming you have not posted the whole code.